# Tensorflow: how to deal with dynamic shape trying to tile and concatenate two tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

I've two tensor, for example `x = [1,2] and y=[3]`, and I want replicate the last along an axis of the other, obtaining `z = [[1,3],[2,3]].` Ideally in tensorflow:

```
x = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 2], dtype = tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(shape=[1], dtype = tf.float32)
z = tf.concat(x, tf.tile(y, [ x.shape[0] ]) , 1)
```

The problem is that x placeholder first dimension is not determined, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()

x = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 2], dtype = tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(shape=[1], dtype = tf.float32)

dim = tf.shape(x)[0]
y1 = tf.expand_dims(y, axis = 1)
y1 = tf.tile(y1, [dim, 1])
z = tf.concat((x, y1), axis = 1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    z_val = sess.run(z, feed_dict = {x:[[2,5],[5,7],[8,9]], y:[3]})
    print(z_val)
```

Output:

```
[[ 2.  5.  3.]
 [ 5.  7.  3.]
 [ 8.  9.  3.]]
```

Comment: Seems to me that this code makes implicit use of the information the input will be 1x2, doesn't work for a 3x2, for example: for feed_dict = {x:[[2,5],[5,7],[8,9]], y:[3]} the output is [[ 2. 5. 5. 3.] [ 7. 8. 9. 3.]] , instead i want [[2,5,3],[5,7,3],[8,9,3]]

Comment: @BernardG, I have generalized the solution now. Have a look.